# Laravel: Duplicate column name when there is a groupBy

Tags: laravel

Why is it that the following error appears when there is a `groupBy` clause in my query.

```
Exception Message:\n\nSQLSTATE[42S21]: Column already exists: 1060 Duplicate column name 'id' (SQL: select count(*) as aggregate from (select * from `schools` inner join `dcp_batch_receives` on `dcp_batch_receives`.`school_id` = `schools`.`id` inner join `lib_districts` on `lib_districts`.`id` = `schools`.`district_id` inner join `lib_divisions` on `lib_divisions`.`id` = `lib_districts`.`division_id` group by `schools`.`id`) count_row_table)
```

This is my query without `groupBy` and is working correctly.

```
        $schools = School::join('dcp_batch_receives', 'dcp_batch_receives.school_id', 'schools.id')
        ->join('lib_districts', 'lib_districts.id', '=', 'schools.district_id')
        ->join('lib_divisions', 'lib_divisions.id', '=', 'lib_districts.division_id');
```

When I add the `groupBy` it gives the above error.

```
        $schools = School::join('dcp_batch_receives', 'dcp_batch_receives.school_id', 'schools.id')
        ->join('lib_districts', 'lib_districts.id', '=', 'schools.district_id')
        ->join('lib_divisions', 'lib_divisions.id', '=', 'lib_districts.division_id')
        ->groupBy('schools.id');
```

Comment: You need to use left joins to be able to aggregate the subquery.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you need to specify the selected fields using something like.

> ->selectRaw("count(*) as name_count,schools.id")

The column name id is specified in 2 tables.